# Convert a binary string to big endian integer in the browser?

Tags: javascript, endianness

I have the following string in binary :

```
const bin = '\x00\x00\x16%'
```

I'd like to convert it in big endian integer.

I was able to do it using the following:

```
new DataView(Uint8Array.from('\x00\x00\x16%', c => c.charCodeAt(0)).buffer).getInt32(0, false)
=> 5669
```

But I'm pretty sure there is asimpler way to do so, rather than convert to an Uint8Array and then pass it to a dataview.

(Note: This is for browser only, not Node.js. I saw all the SO post about `Buffer.readUIntBE`, but they aren't **native** to the browser.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function bin2int(bin) {
            var i = 0;
            var len = bin.length;
            var num = 0;
            while (i < len) {
                num <<= 8;
                num += bin.charCodeAt(i);
                i++;
            }
            return num;
        }
```

This works on the browser and yields the same result. May not be as simple as you'd like it to though

Comment: Nice! Thanks! Just tested it and it works fine!

Answer (score 2):

@moudi answer's put me on the right track so he deserves the accepted, but just for fun:

(updated: An even smaller version, suggested by @adrew-parks):

```js
const stringAsUInt32BE = x => [...x].reduce((a, v) => (a <<= 8) + v.charCodeAt(), 0)

console.log(stringAsUInt32BE('\x00\x00\x16%'))
```

Original answer:

```js
const stringAsUInt32BE = (x) => [...x].reduce((acc, value) => { acc <<= 8; return acc + value.charCodeAt(0) }, 0)

console.log(stringAsUInt32BE('\x00\x00\x16%'))
```

Comment: Btw you can code-golf this as `x=>[...x].reduce((a,v)=>(a<<=8)+v.charCodeAt())` :)

Comment: Also, oops, that code-golf only works if there is a leading null character. It should be: `x=>[...x].reduce((a,v)=>(a<<=8)+v.charCodeAt(),0)`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const s = '\x00\x00\x16%'
const charToHex = c => c.charCodeAt().toString(16)
const n = BigInt('0x'+[...s].map(charToHex).join(''))

console.log(Number(n))
```

Comment: Love it! I'm eager to have many suggestions and see how they compares to the others :)